# How to edit item of listView in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView and show data from database. I’d like to make a simple edit in click of each Item, but my edit function doesn’t work!
This is my edit funciton: (database is an object of SQLiteDatabase class)

```
public Book editBook(Book book, String name, String writer, String year)   {
    long id = book.getId();
    String selection = id + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(id) };

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(sqlHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(sqlHelper.COLUMN_WRITER, writer);
    values.put(sqlHelper.COLUMN_YEAR, year);
    int returnId = database.update(sqlHelper.TABLE,  values,selection,selectionArgs);

    return book;
   }
```

Edit function called in MainActivity like this:

```
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Book data = (Book) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            datasource.editBook(data,data.getName() + " 2014", data.getWriter() + "," + data.getWriter(), data.getYear());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });  
ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Book data = (Book) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            datasource.editBook(data,data.getName() + " 2014", data.getWriter() + "," + data.getWriter(), data.getYear());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post full main activity code. Probably after update, you need to get the data from db again.

Comment: Two times the same code...

Comment: @dieter_h I update list of adapter but still it doesn't work.

  List<Book> items = datasource.getAllBooks();
  adapter.items = items;

Comment: add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or create new instance of adapter object and `setAdaper` to `ListView`

Comment: @dieter_h thansk, edif function was worng because of selection, it have to be : selection = " _id =?"